# Como manipular os valores do curtime

Tags: mysql

Bom dia, eu preciso fazer uma comparação entre um horário que esta salvo em uma tabela e a hora atual do banco de dados, estou utilizando o curtime(), porém na hospedagem que estou utilizando a hora está 2 horas na frente, e não posso alterar, como eu consigo fazer isso

Comment: Esta diferença é devido à Timezone? Também tem as funções DATEDIFF() e TIMEDIFF() que podem ajudar a ver qual a diferença.

Comment: Sim, é devido a TimeZone, porém eu tenho uma PROC que fica executando todo minuto e verificando registros que a hora do usuário bata com a do servidor, porém por conta dessa diferença eu não vou conseguir fazer o calculo com precisão, tentei ate inserir um -2, mas ai não fica legal

Comment: Entendi! Vc já tentou com o TIMEDIFF() na query?
 
SELECT TIMEDIFF(<hora_pc>, CURRENT_TIME);